# How to replicate 500 server error in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am facing the problem while bug fixing. I am trying to provide a handler page for 500 server errors. Sometimes it is throwing 500 server error and sometimes it is not. Can anyone please help to replicate the 500 server error in hybris project.

Answer (score 0):

It is an internal server error. You have to check the backend logs for more information. Possible exceptions and stacktraces. It can be anything. If you want to change the 500 error page, you can find configuration about it in your *storefront extension web.xml file. Here is an example:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/errorPages/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/errorPages/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks Hristo. I already did above changes. But the thing is I am not able to replicate 500 server error to check whether the solution is working fine or not. Is there any way to reproduce the 500 server error.

Comment: For example in one your controllers, try to throw an exception and not handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate so many ways

1)Place a null pointer expection in controller

2)Inproper close of JSP tags